# Prestashop BlockCategories doesn't add "selected" class on active links

Tags: prestashop

I have this standard link in `category-tree-branch.tpl`:

```
<a href="{$node.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{if isset($currentCategoryId) && $node.id == $currentCategoryId} class="selected"{/if} title="{$node.desc|strip_tags|trim|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
    {$node.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
</a>
```

But my links do not have the `selected` class  when active, which causes categories to be closed, hiding subcategories of current category, which ruins the UX completely.

Is there any other info I can give?
Any ideas?

Comment: Place the following code before that link to see if the variable `$currentCategoryId` contains the correct information `{var_dump($currentCategoryId)}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, var dump gives me the "NULL", what could be the problem? The url does show ID without the problem though ("?id_category=13" and so on.)

Comment: Thats more info on the matter: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/445436-class-selected-doas-not-appear-on-active-category-link/

Answer (score 0):

I did fount the solution myself.

```
if ((Tools::getValue('id_product') || Tools::getValue('id_category')) && isset($this->context->cookie->last_visited_category) && $this->context->cookie->last_visited_category)
        {
            $category = new Category($this->context->cookie->last_visited_category, $this->context->language->id);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($category))
                $this->smarty->assign(array('currentCategory' => $category, 'currentCategoryId' => $category->id));
        }
```

This was missing in my function of hook, so there was no value for category ID, thanks UnLoCo for the idea where to look.